# Razor page login form add icon inside input field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, icons

I am working on a Razor Page Web Application in .NetCore and I am doing this Login page where the user must insert an email and a password. In the input fields I want to have 2 icons and I tried using font awesome ones but the icon is added outside of the field and not inside. I also tried adding an image but it works the same. Is there any way I can add the icon inside the input field?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control u-input-width">  
         <i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
    </input>
    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add an input group like: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/

Comment: Not quite like that because I need my icon to be inside the input field not near it. I added a new photo to show how it should look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put icon in the right of input.Here is a demo:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa icon"> </i>
            <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control u-input-width" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
 </div>
<style>
    .inputContainer {
        position: relative;
    }
    .icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: auto;
        right: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
#mainDiv {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.elementDiv i {
  position: absolute;
}

.elementDiv {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 40px;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h3>
    Icon inside input element demo
  </h3>
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div class="elementDiv">
      <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Enter details">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```